# fourier series of $|\sin x|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, fourier-series

I need to find the fourier series of $$|\sin x|$$.
Im not sure my way is right, would be happy if someone fix me.
I found $$a_0=4/\pi$$, the function is even, so $$b_n=0$$ but how do I calculate:
$$a_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(1/\pi)|\sin(x)|\cos(nx)dx$$

Comment: Please do pay attention to your typing before you post your question...

Comment: Hint: $|\sin x|\cos (nx)$ is even, so this is twice the integral over $[0,\pi]$..

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{2\pi}$? Also, I added $n$ to $\cos(nx)$ in the definition of $a_n$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I saw in lecture 1/pi

Comment: [$\frac{1}{\pi}$ it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Example_1:_a_simple_Fourier_series).

Comment: @julien if its even I can make it 2*integral [0,pi]?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Where $|\sin x|=\sin x$.

Comment: but how do I handle cos(nx)? never saw it before

Comment: [$\sin a \cos b= $...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

Comment: Doesn't that identity transpasses the problem from cosine to sines, @julien ?

Comment: @DonAntonio It transforms the integrand (product of sine and cosine) into a sum of sines which have easy antiderivatives.

Comment: Oh, of course! I forgot what we were trying to do here. Nice. +1

Answer (score 14):

The function $x\mapsto f(x):=|\sin x|$ is even and $\pi$-periodic; therefore  $f$ has a Fourier series of the form
$$f(x)={a_0\over2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(2kx)$$
with
$$a_k={2\over\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\cos(2k x)\ dx={2\over\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin x\cos(2k x)\ dx\ .$$
It follows that
$$\eqalign{a_k&={1\over\pi}\int_0^\pi\left(\sin\bigl((1+2k)x\bigr)+\sin\bigl((1-2k)x\bigr)\right)\ dx\cr &={1\over\pi}\left({\cos\bigl((2k-1)x\bigr)\over 2k-1}-{\cos\bigl((2k+1)x\bigr)\over 2k+1}\right)\Biggr|_0^\pi\cr &={2\over\pi}\left({1\over 2k+1}-{1\over 2k-1}\right)=-{4\over\pi(4k^2-1)}\cr}\ .$$
Therefore we have
$$|\sin x|={2\over\pi}-{4\over\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\cos(2k x)\over 4k^2-1}\qquad(-\infty < x<\infty)\ .$$

Comment: Why does one get $2kx$ inside $\cos$ in the first $a_k$?

Comment: @mavavilj: Because the period length  is not $2\pi$, but $\pi$. Use the formula for arbitrary period length $L$ with $L=\pi\,$!

Comment: You mean put $L=\pi$ and then consider "well I need two of these"? https://www.math24.net/fourier-series-functions-arbitrary-period/. So multiply the entirety of what's inside $\cos$?

Comment: "In three books, the Fourier series coefficients are in different forms. I don't understand why they are equivalent." https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661597/fourier-coefficients-for-an-arbitrary-period-different-forms