# Fourier coefficients for an arbitrary period, different forms?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In three books, the Fourier series coefficients are in different forms.
I don't understand why they are equivalent.

From book 1:
\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{1}{L}\int_ {-L}^{L}f(t)\cos\Big(\frac{\pi n}{L}t\Big)\, dt\tag 1 \\
b_n&=\frac{1}{L}\int_ {-L}^{L}f(t)\sin\Big(\frac{\pi n}{L}t\Big)\, dt\tag 2
\end{align}

From book 2:

\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{2}{L}\int_ {-L/2}^{L/2}f(t)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n}{L}t\Big)\, dt\tag 3 \\
b_n&=\frac{2}{L}\int_ {-L/2}^{L/2}f(t)\sin\Big(\frac{2\pi n}{L}t\Big)\, dt\tag 4
\end{align}

From book 3:
\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{2}{L}\int_ {0}^{L}f(t)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n}{L}t\Big)\, dt\tag 5 \\
b_n&=\frac{2}{L}\int_ {0}^{L}f(t)\sin\Big(\frac{2\pi n}{L}t\Big)\, dt\tag 6
\end{align}

Eq. $(1)-(2)$ don't have the extra factor of 2, why?

Can we find $(5)-(6)$ by changing the limits $[-L/2,L/2]=[0,L]$ in $(3)-(4)$?

Comment: L is typically T/2, where T is the time period. I suspect (3), (4) should have T not L. Then (1),(2) and (3),(4) would be the same thing. (5) and (6) apply when $f(t)$ is even or odd respectively (though (5) should include $b_n = 0$ and (6) should include $a_n = 0$). The 2 should not be inside the sin or cos though so they are wrong as written.

Answer (score 1):

Context is all. In the case of Fourier series there are several variations depending on the context. We assume we have a function $f(t)$ with period $T$. The Fourier series coefficients depend on the values of $f(t)$ on an interval of length $T$. In the case of book 1, $T=2L$ and the interval is $[-L,L]$. For the other two books, $T=L$. For book 2 the interval is $[-L/2,L/2]$ and for book 3 $[0,L]$. The common factor for all the integrals is $2/T.$ Expressing that in terms of $L$ yields some variations.